# Jointjs creating link once it is deleted

Tags: jointjs

I have recently started working with JointJS. I have not seen any example/tutorial on their website mentioning creating of link again once it is deleted. For example on this link.

http://jointjs.com/demos/org

I wonder if its possible to create the link again between the two Members once it is deleted.

I tried with this code in the function `function (x, y, rank, background, textColor)`:

```
'.rank': { text: rank, fill: textColor, 'word-spacing': '-5px', 'letter-spacing': 0, magnet: true, pointerevents:'none' }
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the member type has ports. If yes you need to add ports to recreate the links once rendered. If you look at the source code, the links are created during render so if you refresh the page or run the code again the links come back.